# Show an alert from hour X to hour Y

Tags: php

Hi I want to show an alert from hour X to hour Y

I have:

```
  $currday = date('l');
    $starting_hour = DB::table('time')->select('starting_hour')->where('day' == $currday)->get();
    $ending_hour = DB::table('time')->select('ending_hour')->where('day' == $currday)->get();
    $currhour = date('H')

    if($currhour > $starting_hour || $currhour < $ending_hour)
       return 'yes alert';
    else
       return 'no alert';
```

Assuming the `$currhour` is equal to 11. Here is a problem beacause I want to show this alert only if the currhour is on the interval 18 - 22. Another case is when the interval 18 - 9 (the next day).. here will work well because 11 it's < than 18 and 11 it's > than 9..

How can I solve all of the case?

**EDIT**:
CASES USING `||`

CASE 1:

```
$starting_h = 16;
$ending_h = 22;
$currenthour = 5;
```

if i'm using

```
if($currhour >= 16 || $currhour <= 22)
```

will return true.. but I want to return this alert only at: 16,17,18,19...22

CASE 2:

```
$starting_h = 16;
$ending_h = 5;
$currenthour = 4;

  if($currhour >= 16 || $currhour <= 5)
```

Here it's ok on any combination..

CASES USING `&&`

CASE 1:

```
$starting_h = 16;
$ending_h = 5;
$currenthour = 4;

if($currhour >= 16 && $currhour <= 5)
```

=> not ok, because I want to display the message on interval 16PM-5AM and now 4 < 16.

CASE 2:

```
$starting_h = 16;
$ending_h = 5;
$currenthour = 4;

if($currhour >= 16 && $currhour <= 5)
```

Here will work on any combination..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check the start time and end time first.

```
$currhour = date('H')
$start = 18;
$end = 9;

if($start < $end &&  $currhour > $start && $currhour < $end)
   return 'yes alert';
else if ($start > $end) {
   if ($currhour < $start && $currhour > $end)
      return 'no alert';
   else
      return 'yes alert';
} 
else
   return 'no alert';
```

You could even shorter it to the below if you want to wrap it in a function

```
function showAlert($start, $end)
{
    $currhour = date('H')

    if($start < $end &&  $currhour >= $start && $currhour <= $end)
        return 'yes alert';
    else if ($start > $end) {
        if ($currhour > $start && $currhour < $end)
            return 'yes alert';
    }

    return 'no alert';
}

showAlert(18, 9);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little the way you've thinked?

Comment: the first condition means the start and the end points in same day, the second means it in 2 days, the condition ($currhour < $start && $currhour > $end) mean this not time for alert (it is easier too check for no alert). I drew a line to find the condition, it will make easy to understand

Comment: i just find an easy way, but if you want to do it I think the hint is "use timestame" for more condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` not `||`

```
$currhour = date('H')

if($currhour > 18 && $currhour < 22)
    return 'yes alert';
else
    return 'no alert';
```

Comment: @lan i've edited my post I saw ... but the problem still remain..because 11 < 22

Comment: @Argift65, it doesn't matter, because there's `&&` between the conditions. So you get 'yes alert' only if the current hour is bigger than 18 AND smaller than 22.

Comment: @walther and if I change 22 with 5 and currhour is equal with 4:00:00. What should I do? Because it's 4 in the morning

Comment: @Argift65, once again, if you need to determine if the current hour is within a given interval, you need to use `&&`, otherwise it will never work. Furthermore, I don't really understand what's the problem. This is a fairly simple scenario. If you have problems finding the correct algorithm, take a step back and start with even more basic problems and try to find a solution.

Comment: @walther the problem is when..i'm on the next day..because if current hour is 2.....starting hour 18 and ending hour is 5..will show me 'no alert';..

Comment: @Argift65, if you need to have hours spanning through multiple days, you need to take the current day into account as well and check accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the comparison between the starting hour configured and ending hour to discover if the hours in the morning will be acceptable.

```
$currhour = date('H');


if(($ending_hour > $starting_hour && ($currhour > $starting_hour && $currhour < $ending_hour)) || ($starting_hour > $ending_hour && ($currhour > $starting_hour || $currhour < $ending_hour)))
    return 'yes alert';
else
    return 'no alert';
```

Comment: Think at values 18,22 etc... It will be dynamic. Always I need to compare..currhour > starting_date  currhour < ending_date.

Comment: You can store then in the session the previous values, can't you?

Comment: @Carols Alexandre ..i've edited my post.. So my intervals need to be dynamic like in the example. I have an admin panel where I will change starting_hour and ending_hour.